# Kubernetes always uses the same replica

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

I have created deployment which has a service. I set it to run it in 5 replicas. When I call the service it always uses the same replica (pod). Is there a way how to use round robin instead, so all pods will be used?
[image]

Comment: k8s does that by default. If it's not doing it for you you'll have to provide much more info about your setup. For example, your service, how your services are implemented (kube proxy I assume). As a starter, can you check if the label selector in the Service is correctly selecting the pods you expect it to? Also is there any stickiness configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access your pods by service name, you get an IP address for one of the pods and use it in subsequent requests.

To solve this problem, you can create an ingress and use the url instead of the service name, in this case you will get an IP address on each request, and the load will be distributed between the pods.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Kubernetes distributes the traffic to all the service endpoints in a `round-robin` fashion. **Although**, this behavior can be changed if you use `kube-proxy` in `IPVS` mode. With `IPVS` mode, you can change the traffic distribution algorithms to something else.

To check the mode of the `kube-proxy`:(it should be either `iptables` or `ipvs` or `blank`)

```
kubectl get cm -n kube-system  kube-proxy -o jsonpath='{.data.config\.conf}{"\n"}' |grep mode
```

If the mode is blank or iptables, the traffic is distributed round-robin. **However**, if the mode is set to `ipvs`, *things will get interesting*. You will have to check the `scheduler` field under the ipvs. E.g.:

```
kubectl get cm -n kube-system  kube-proxy -o jsonpath='{.data.config\.conf}{"\n"}' |grep -ozP '(?s)ipvs:.*?(?=kind:)'
ipvs:
  excludeCIDRs: []
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  scheduler: rr                              #<----rr here means round-robin
  strictARP: false
  syncPeriod: 30s
  tcpFinTimeout: 0s
  tcpTimeout: 0s
  udpTimeout: 0s
```

The `IPVS` supports other traffic distribution algorithms, like:

> rr: round-robin  Robin Robin: distributes jobs equally amongst the
> available real servers.
>
> lc: least connection (smallest number of open connections)
> Least-Connection: assigns more jobs to real servers with fewer active
> jobs.
>
> dh: destination hashing Destination Hashing: assigns jobs to servers
> by looking up a statically assigned hash table by their destination IP
> addresses.
>
> sh: source hashing Source Hashing: assigns jobs to servers by looking
> up a statically assigned hash table by their source IP addresses.
>
> sed: shortest expected delay Shortest Expected Delay: assigns an
> incoming job to the server with the shortest expected delay. The
> expected delay that the job will experience is (Ci + 1) / Ui if sent
> to the ith server, in which Ci is the number of jobs on the ith server
> and Ui is the fixed service rate (weight) of the ith server.
>
> nq: never queue Never Queue: assigns an incoming job to an idle server
> if there is, instead of waiting for a fast one; if all the servers are
> busy, it adopts the Shortest Expected Delay policy to assign the job.

If you decide to play around with the different values, then you would have to edit the configmap:

```
kubectl edit cm -n kube-system  kube-proxy
```

And restart the `daemonset` for kube-proxy:

```
kubectl rollout restart ds kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

You may find some exciting read about load balancing for services [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/) and [here](https://technekey.com/changing-the-traffic-distribution-of-a-kubernetes-service/).
**Note**, if you have service mesh(like `istio`) installed in your cluster and virtual services in play, then it's beyond the scope of this answer.